# Get Selected Properties of Parameters of a Powershell CmdLet

Tags: powershell, select-object

Given any Cmdlet (Powershell v3) I want to get a list of the parameters with only selected properties (e.g. name and type).  The output as JSON should something like:

```
[
        {
                "Name":  "Path",
                "ParameterType":  "string"
        },
        {
                "Name":  "Filter",
                "ParameterType":  "string"
        },
        {
                "Name":  "Recurse",
                "ParameterType":  "switch"
        }
]
```

I have the collection of parameters but I cannot seem to select only those parameters I want:

```
$cmd = gcm Get-ChildItem
$parameters = $cmd.Parameters.Values
for($i=0; $i -lt $parameters.Count; $i++) {
        $parameters[$i] = Select-Object Name,ParameterType -InputObject $parameters[$i]
}
$parameters | ConvertTo-JSON -depth 1
```

I get all parameters:

```
[
        {
                "Name":  "Path",
                "ParameterType":  "string",
                "ParameterSets":  "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]",
                "IsDynamic":  false,
                "Aliases":  "",
                "Attributes":  "System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute",
                "SwitchParameter":  false
        },
        {
                "Name":  "Filter",
                "ParameterType":  "string",
                "ParameterSets":  "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata]",
                "IsDynamic":  false,
                "Aliases":  "",
                "Attributes":  "System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute",
                "SwitchParameter":  false
        },
...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cmd = gcm Get-ChildItem
$cmd.Parameters.Values |
    Select Name,ParameterType,SwitchParameter |
   ConvertTo-Json -depth 1
```

Result:

```
[
        {
                "Name":  "Path",
                "ParameterType":  "string[]",
                "SwitchParameter":  false
        },
        {
                "Name":  "LiteralPath",
                "ParameterType":  "string[]",
                "SwitchParameter":  false
        },
        {
                "Name":  "Filter",
                "ParameterType":  "string",
                "SwitchParameter":  false
        },
        ...
]
```

Comment: You do not really need `foreach` here.